# query on mongodb attributes that exist inside another foreign key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've 3 different schema -

1. Organization
2. Site
3. Task

Each Task is linked to a Site and each Site belongs to an organization.

**Organization schema**

```
{
  name: String,
  _id: String,
}
```

**Site Schema**

```
{
  name: String,
  _id: String,
  organization:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Organization',
    required: true
  }
}
```

**Task schema** -

```
{
  title: String,
  _id: String,
  site:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Site',
    required: true
  }
}
```

Problem - *I need to get all the tasks that belong to a particular organization*.

How can I do this in mongodb? A query for the same would be really helpful.

Comment: You may use $lookup for this task , but using lookup in mongodb mean that your schema design may need changes ...

Comment: @R2D2 could you please share some insights about how these updates can be made?

Comment: please, provide example documents and example output on what is expected so it is easy for us to prepare the necessary query ...

Comment: It seems in your Task schema you just need to add few more fields for Site & Organization and you dont need all those joins/lookups ...

Comment: Yeah, I've simply added the organization and site details to the Task schema for quick solution. I had this in my mind but thought of asking community, if there's something that I might be missing on. 

thanks @R2D2